# While removing index.php from url in codeigniter, i am getting following error .Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

While removing index.php from URL, I am getting an error Not found

From :- http://localhost/Inspire/index.php/welcome/dashboard

to this

http://localhost/Inspire/welcome/dashboard

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]



config.php



$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Could you please do let us know from which URL to which URL you are trying to redirect here for more clarity please

Comment: Please go through the question now.

Comment: $config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI" change AUTO with this

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: where you are creating .htaccess file??

Comment: Its inside the application folder

Comment: @Abhishek have you solve your problem or not??

Comment: Sir, it's not resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeigniter 4 have two different .htaccess files, you need to change the one in public folder:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Your Comment Its inside the application folder so its wrong.
You should create it inside root website folder.

**Step:-1** Go to your CodeIgniter root folder and create `.htaccess`

```
Path:
Your_website_folder/
.htaccess <——— this file
    application/
    assets/
    system/
    index.php
```

Write below code in `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

**Step:-2** Open the folder `application/config` and open the file `config.php`. find and replace the below code in `config.php` file.

```
//find the below code   
$config['index_page'] = "index.php" 
//replace with the below code
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

from htaccess file in public folder to:

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: still need QSA for linux based servers

Comment: For some reason, I didn't need that on our Debian server. Can you explain me what it signifies ?